# $_SESSION[' '] into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, phpmyadmin

I already have values in `$_SESSION[' ']` from the `customer` table in phpmyadmin (in the table it contains `id`, `cust_name`, `cust_firstname`, `cust_lastname`, `cust_add`, `cust_tel`, and `cust_email`), i use this for log in purpose.

And then in my `SessionHandler.php` i declare something like

```
//check whether the query was successful or not
if(isset($result))
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        //Login successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_EMAIL'] = $member['cust_email'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_NAME'] = $member['cust_name'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_FIRST'] = $member['cust_firstname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_ADD'] = $member['cust_add'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_TEL'] = $member['cust_tel'];
        $_SESSION['STATUS'] = true;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: http://localhost/wedding/user/dresses.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        //login failed
        header("location: cust-login-failed.html");
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    die("Query failed");
}
```

so,whenever someone log in i will only used `<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_FIRST'] ?>`
The thing is, i'm doing a shopping cart, and i want the customer name who is log in or in other word i want `$_SESSION['SESS_CUST_FIRST']` to be inserted into the database in new table name `order` which has `id`, `product_name`, `product_code`, `price`, `product_size`, `product_qty` and `cust_firstname`.

This is the form in the dress page that have the button add to cart:

```
<form method="POST" action="dress-isikan.php">

<table>

<tr>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="5"><img src="/wedding/dress/Large/01.jpg"></td>
  <td style="vertical-align: top;"><big style="font-family: DFKai-SB;">Tulip Wedding Dress (WD01)<input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Tulip Dress">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="WD01"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="vertical-align: top;">Beautiful tulip wedding dress with flower lace on the chest</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
  <td style="vertical-align: top;">Price: RM 799
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="799.00"><br>
  <br>
Size :</big>
      <select name="product_size">
      <option>34</option>
      <option>36</option>
      <option>38</option>
      <option>40</option>
      <option>42</option>
      <option>44</option>
      <option>46</option>
      <option>48</option>
      </select>
      </big> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><br><big><big>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_FIRST']; ?>" name="$cust_name;">
Quantity:</big></big> <input type="number" name="product_qty" min="1" max="11" value="1"><br>
<br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add to cart" ><br>

      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

But whenever i start to add to cart and it will be submitted to `dress-isikan.php` first:

```
<!-- dress-isikan.php -->
<!-- To insert data of masuk.php into database. -->
<?php

include("dress-dbase.php");

extract( $_POST );
$query = "INSERT INTO order VALUES ('', '$cust_name', '$product_name','$product_code','$price','$product_qty','$product_size')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die("Could not execute query in dress-isikan.php");
if($result) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location='checkout.php' </script>";
}
?>
```

it will says could not execute query in `dress-isikan.php`, i don't know what is wrong with the query. I think i've done nothing wrong. And sometimes it always have problem with the `$_SESSION['  ']` thing that i try to submit it into database table `order`. I just follow my lecture notes. Does anyone know?

Comment: From a developer point of view, I think you're going about storing information the wrong way. $_SESSION information is what the server keeps as you're moving through different pages on the site and is stored temporarily (such as shopping basket information and the fact you're "logged in"). With regards to your USER information you should load the information from the database into a user object and refer to their name, email etc. from the object when your user logs in. When they make an order and you go through to the "checkout" process THEN you can read from your $_SESSION data.

Comment: I have 2 things.  1) Have you tried listing the fields you're inserting?  `INSERT INTO order (field1, field2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2')`;  2) Please, please, PLEASE don't use mysql_* functions.  It's a great way to allow users to do what's called SQL injections.  Please look into PDO MySQL (http://us2.php.net/pdo_mysql) or MySQLi (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: @Nadia Perry make an `echo $query;` just before calling `mysql_query`and copy the string query printed with **echo** and excute it directly on _phpmyadmin_ this should give you much more informations about your sql errors.

Comment: @kyle i've tried listing the fields `"INSERT INTO order (id,cust_name, product_name,product_code, price,product_qty, product_size) 
VALUES ('', '$cust_name', '$product_name','$product_code','$price','$product_qty','$product_size')"` but then it says undefined variable `cust_name`.

Comment: @faresM. i don't really understand, can you show me?

Comment: @BigChris i get your point, but how to do it? I still trying to code anything with that logic but it didn't work

Comment: @NadiaPerry You never show where you've set your variables.  Please provide that code.  As the error says, it sounds like `cust_name` isn't set anywhere.

Comment: @kyle i've set it in the form `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_FIRST']; ?>" name="cust_name;">` Or i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @NadiaPerry okay, first thing to do is enabling php error reporting, so put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script **dress-isikan.php** after the **php** tag, make an `echo $query` just before `$result = mysql_query($query, $conn)` line, now, test your script on browser to see the `$query` string value, copy it and execute on the sql tab of phpmyadmin and tell me what you got on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @FaresM. the error says `undefined variable: cust_name in` blablabla `INSERT INTO order (id, product_name, product_code, price, product_qty, product_size, cust_name) 
VALUES ('', 'Tulip Dress','WD01','799.00','1','34', '')";` the column in `cust_name` have nothing. I think i've doing it wrong to put `$_SESSION['SESS_CUST_NAME']` in the database. I'm so lost

Comment: @NadiaPerry try with this `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_FIRST']; ?>" name="cust_name">` instead of `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_CUST_FIRST']; ?>" name="$cust_name;">
`

Comment: @FaresM. the same thing happen :(

Comment: @FaresM. omg thank you! i'm so silly